# When I try to do anything to my android google map API map other than show the default my app crashes

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an app that has a mapfragment in a page.  I am trying to get the fragment to show three markers (in the end the camera will frame the markers too, but I just want to get it to work!).

So I do this:

```
//Includes//
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.GetMetadataRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
//end includes

//Class level variables//
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private int mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
//end class level variables//

//Begin setting up my map//
            FragmentManager fragMan =   new FragmentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)fragMan.findFragmentById(R.id.frgMap);
            googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();

            LatLng originCoords = new LatLng(Long.parseLong(hash.get("OriginLat")), Long.parseLong(hash.get("OriginLong")));
            LatLng destCoords = new LatLng(Long.parseLong(hash.get("DestLat")), Long.parseLong(hash.get("DestLong")));
            LatLng myCoords = new LatLng(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
            googleMap.setMapType(mapType);

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myCoords).title("My Current Position").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(originCoords).title("Package Origin").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET)));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destCoords).title("Package Destination").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
//end setting up map
//Begin the flow of frustrated tears and gnashing of teeth
```

and this is as far as I get.  When I debug it it doesn't throw any exceptions, but I get the thrice accursed "Source not found" error, which doesn't give me a whole lot to go on.  What should I be looking at to fix this?  Do I have a JAR or .java file that I need to put in the sources folder of my android SDK?

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: google maps android api-2

Comment: for v2 your MapActivity shoud extends Activity and not MapActivity check if it's the case.

Comment: It extends FragmentActivity, since it's a fragment.

Comment: are you getting compile time error or runtime ?

Comment: Essentially my logcat and debug screens are error free.  The app crashes with no error, but it says "Source not found." similar to this: [link](http://branchbird.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/source-not-found.png)

Comment: Do you have the Google Play Services app installed on the device?

Comment: Yes.  I can get the map to work by using the demo code from the website, but as soon as I try *anything* more complex it poops out on me.